# high contrast mode for icons had disappeared

Tags: android-device-manager, android-x86, samsung-galaxy-s-9

That worked, except now the option in Settings has disappeared and I can't reveal it a anymore.

Android SM_696U0 (Samsung Galaxy S9)

**Removed here:**

[image: it was removed here:]

Answer (score 0):

I was snore able to fix this by opening a third-party app that had an "invert colors" toggle.

Flipping that on/off restored default colors across Android.

Vey strange.

Comment: Linking which app would help others with same problem

Comment: Since this answer mentions "invert colors" (I'm assuming "high contrast mode" is a bit different), then try checking the Accessibility settings. Some devices have "invert colors" on there.